# Using IsNumeric Function in a Formula

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-formula, isnumeric

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong, or if it's even possible.

I am working with 3 columns:
Column X = # of Services, Column Y = # of Bills, and Column Z which is a calculation of X divided by Y.

Sometimes, there is a text entry in Column X - when that happens, I want Column Z to simply reflect what Column Y contains.

Here is the code I've written...  I've tried (seemingly) all possible combinations of quotation marks and parentheses, to no avail.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(IsNumeric(RC[-2]),=RC[-2]/RC[-1],=RC[-1])"
```

Thank you!

Comment: remove the `=` after the first one.

Comment: also `IsNumeric` is a VBA function. Its equivalent function is `IsNumber`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is wrong, use this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(IsNumber(RC[-2]),RC[-2]*RC[-1],RC[-1])"
```

Note that `IsNumeric` is a VBA function and its equivalent in Excel functions is `IsNumber`. Sometimes functions have different names for Excel and VBA, this is one of the cases.

Comment: please check it as the right answer then! :) upper left corner checkmark ;)